# Pipe successfully sorting and logging data, but not displaying in html

Tags: angular, sorting, ionic-framework, pipe, ngfor

The sorting function on date-descned.ts does work because the data it logs (seen below) is in descending order. But, the data will not display in the html when I run the page. Is there something wrong with the pipe formatting  in the *ngFor statement in the html, or something incorrect about the return statement in the .ts file? I am developing in ionic framework using lazy loading. The pipe successfully returns and displays data on the html when I have something simple like return 'hello', so I don't believe it's a problem with the pages being linked incorrectly.

Dashboard.html

```
  <ion-card-content *ngFor = "let step of stepNumber | dateDescend">
    <p>Date: {{step.date}}</p>
    <p>Steps: {{step.steps }}</p>
  </ion-card-content>
```

date-descend.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'dateDescend',
})
export class DateDescendPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array: Array<string>, args: string) {
  console.log('array', array)
  setTimeout(() => {
      array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
        if (a.date < b.date) {
          return -1;
          console.log('here1')
        } else if (a.date > b.date) {
          return 1;
          console.log('here2')
        } else {
          return 0;
          console.log('here3')
        }
      });
      console.log('FinalArray', array)
      return array;
      }, 3000);
    }
}
```

console.log('FinalArray', array) returns

```
0 {steps: 67, date: "July 12, 2018"}
1 {steps: 8, date: "July 13, 2018"}
2 {steps: 9, date: "July 14, 2018"}
3 {steps: 89, date: "July 15, 2018”}
4 {steps: 67, date: "July 18, 2018"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is right here:

```
setTimeout(() => {
      array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
        if (a.date < b.date) {
          return -1;
          console.log('here1')
        } else if (a.date > b.date) {
          return 1;
          console.log('here2')
        } else {
          return 0;
          console.log('here3')
        }
      });
      console.log('FinalArray', array)
      return array;
      }, 3000);
    }
```

Notice that the argument you pass to setTimeout is a function. So your return statement, simply will return to the execution of the setTimeout, it's not returning from the `transform` function, not to mention that setTimeout runs your function asynchronously, and I see no reason for that in your case. Remove it and put your code outside and it should work correctly.